# Flex Keeps compiling old files

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

I'm working on a project on Flex AS3.0 project in Flex Builder. It was working fine, I changed the name of one of my classes and all the related process. Now when I compile dubug the thing, it keeps on compiling an older version even if I comment all the code in main. It still compiles the old files. I have cleaned the project , but still the same old problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to be an SVN Issue, I made the debug folder and the html-template folder not to check into SVN and it works fine now.